# Why am I getting no output on list

Tags: python, list, computer-science

I have to write a function find that takes a lists and an element and returns the index of the first occurence of the element in the list or if not there, -1 
And no this question is not similar to the other question about index please quit saying it is on post!

I keep getting no output back on python Idle! Can you please help the program work.

```
def find(myList,myElement):
    i=0
    while i<len(myList) and myList(i)!=myElement:
     i+=1
    if myList(i)==myElement:
     return i
     else:
    return -1
    len(myList)==7
    i==7
```

Comment: `return myList.index(myElement)`

Comment: Please fix your indentation according to PEP 8.

Comment: I would have assumed you would get different errors if you indexed using those parantheses

Comment: Duplicate of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27368078/189134

Answer (score 1):

[`List.index()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) is doing the exact same thing:

```
def find(myList, myElement):
    return myList.index(myElement)
```

For the future, Python gives you many ways to iterate over a list, what you tried is quite obscure. Use [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) or [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) in the future:

```
def find(myList, myElement):
    for i, elem in enumerate(myList):
        if myElement == elem:
            return i
    return -1
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I've tried running it and I get no output as well Im so confused

Comment: How do you call this method and print its output?

Comment: I believe its suppose to output a list of numbers up to 7 that are assigned for example if I say 43 was first in the list and I enter 1 the output is suppose say 43 and so on.

Comment: Then you don't want to "find" the index of a element, you want to return it. When the variable `myList` is your list, you can access the first element with `myList[0]`. You probably should read some tutorials about lists, [this one](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
def finds(myList,myElement):
    i=0
    while i<len(myList) and myList[i]!=myElement:
        i+=1
    if i!=len(myList) and myList[i]==myElement:
        return i
    else:
        return -1

print finds(["a","b","c"],"b")
```

I tried this.It is working fine.You had use `myList(i)` which should be `myList[i]`

Comment: thanks im unsure if this way the way or not but I remember he showed the answer and he entered the number 1 and it displayed the first number on the list which was 43 im unsure I hope you know what im talking about.

Comment: @juggacode m not getting you.This is a working code.You can try it out in your editor

Comment: well for instance you know how you entered a b c say a was a number instead and that was 50 and you wanted to print the first second or third number by inputing 1 2 or 3 what would you do?

Comment: never mind I found out I meant this lol mylist=[10, 20, 30, 40]
a=int(input('Enter list value:' ))
print(mylist[a])